# Why MISRA-C checker gives error checking STM32 HAL?

Tags: c, stm32, microcontroller, hal, misra

I've started a project with HAL library using stm32cubemx, but there seems to be an HAL and MISRA-C compliance problem.

I'm using Keil for my software development and I've added PC-Lint (MISRA-C checker) to check C standards. When I run PC-lint to check MISRA-C rules, I receive lots of MISRA-C 2012 violation rules that arises from HAL commands.

Note, I have not entered any source files other than those generated by stm32cube.

For example, the generated files contains these two lines:

```c
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
__attribute__((section(".revsh_text"))) __STATIC_INLINE __ASM int16_t __REVSH(int16_t value)
```

but I receive these errors consequently:

```
: Note 934: Taking address of near auto variable 'GPIO_InitStruct' (arg. no. 2) [MISRA 2012 Rule 1.3, required]
__attribute__((section(".revsh_text"))) __STATIC_INLINE __ASM int16_t __REVSH(int16_t value)
```

I also receive lots of other errors. According to [this](https://www.st.com/resource/en/brochure/brstm32cube.pdf) , HAL is in compliance with MISRA C 2012. What is wrong?

Comment: `According to this` According to ... ?

Comment: sorry, I corrected the link;  https://www.st.com/resource/en/brochure/brstm32cube.pdf

Comment: `HAL and LL APIs are production–ready, developed in compliance with MISRA-C®:2012 guidelines and checked with CodeSonar static analysis tool. Reports are available on demand` Ask for report. The statement is that the __APIs__ are compliant, not the implementation, I guess.

Comment: what did st say when you contacted them about this issue?

Comment: I didn't ask them, but when I asked it on the st forum, someone answered that the mcu model I use, is not supported by misra. well that was wrong either.

Answer (score 2):

Most board support packages result in violations of MISRA C rules.

This is because, generally, these BSPs are doing things that (most of the time) are not good ideas.  Sometimes, they are necessary (eg memory mapped registers require a conversion of an integer to a pointer, although this *can* be done in the linker)

They often also include lots of compiler specific magic (so Rule 1.1, Rule 1.2 and Directive 1.1 are worth proper review!)

So you need to separate your violations into three groups.

1. Correct violations that need fixing
2. Necessary violations that need a deviation
3. Advisory violations that you can accept (and document your reasoning)

Remember: Deviations are an acceptable aspect of MISRA Compliance!  Any clip-board monitor that says you are not allowed Deviations needs some re-education.

For group 2, MISRA has published some Deviation Permits to help you...

Disclaimer: See profile

PS: and to save @Lundin making his comment, and notwithstanding my professional affiliation, PC-Lint is not the best choice of analyser.

-- Edited --

> According to this , HAL is in compliance with MISRA C 2012.

According to the (now added) link

> HAL and LL APIs are production–ready, developed in compliance with
> MISRA-C®:2012 guidelines and checked with CodeSonar static analysis
> tool. Reports are available on demand.

You need to ask for those reports and see what they say.  I'm tempted to ask for them myself.......

Since they are claiming Compliance with MISRA C 2012, there will be a Guideline Compliance Summary (as well as a few other things)... if not, they are not compliant.

Comment: yes the link is this:  https://www.st.com/resource/en/brochure/brstm32cube.pdf

Answer (score 1):

There are two different issues here: the static analyser tool and the ST library:

---

Rule 1.3 just says you should have no undefined or critically unspecified behavior in your program. A very broad and vague rule. Returning a pointer to a local variable *from* a function would have been a violation of that rule. Passing a pointer to a local variable *to* a function is not. `HAL_GPIO_Init` doesn't do anything with that pointer other than reading it.

This is what we call "false positive", also known as tool bug. Ask your tool vendor why their tool gives incorrect diagnostic messages.

---

*However*, since `HAL_GPIO_Init` doesn't modify the passed pointer, it should have declared the function as:

```
void HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIO_TypeDef  *GPIOx, const GPIO_InitTypeDef *GPIO_Init)`
```

Since they did not, it is a MISRA-C violation of rule 8.13. The function is *not* MISRA compliant unless there are documented deviations. The source Doxygen comments for the implementation of this function (that I admittedly found on some random Github) doesn't mention MISRA at all, so it is pretty safe to assume that the library is not MISRA compliant.

Answer (score -2):

It is not the HAL library problem only a problem with your code (even if it was generated by the Cube.

What is wrong here?

You pass the reference to the local variable. Everything is fine if the code id single threaded or the called function will not use the data after the function returns.

But (even if you do not multithread) many functions will work in the background. For example *_IT and *_DMA functions. You you pass the reference to the buffer having autoatic storage duration you will be in big problems.

So the Lint is correct. You do a potentially dangerous operation.

Comment: Yes I know that it is a potential danger to pass the reference, but It has been clamed that HAL is compliant with misra c which is not correct!

Comment: @AminKhorsandi But **it is not** the HAL library. It is **user code**. It is **your** responsibility to make it **save** and **compliant**